# I want to create Netsuite non inventory sale item using REST API but getting error for tax schedule

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create non inventory sale item in netsuite using REST API but not able to do that because of payload issue.

If I am passing `taxSchedule` then it gives below error

[image]

And if I'm not passing then it gives below error

[image]

what am I missing?

I have tried with different ways to figure out but didn't get the solution

Comment: Well, my guess is that `taxSchedule` and `Tax Schedule` are not the same thing

Comment: In NetSuite documentation `taxSchedule` is a required field for creating Non-Inventory sale items. So based on that `taxSchedule` and `Tax Schedule` might be the same.